# Pause Nagios reloading in web interface

Tags: nagios

Is there any option how could I turn off reloading of web page in Nagios web interface? Many times I checked many services and I needed the webpage to stay static and don't reload.

One solution come to my mind - turn off the whole reloading for a while. Problem is that other people are using it too and they may want it at the time I don't want it. If anybody know about any kind of workaround or solution, please don't hesitate to write an answer. ;-)

*EDIT (+ reaction to the first answer)*: Maybe there could be a better way how to do it instead of modyfying nagios core. Interesting is, that I tried to disable javascript, it refreshed. I tried to disable http refreshing, it refreshed anyway. Has anybody know how and where is the refresh implemented?

Answer (score 4):

There's a ~3 year old patch floating on the nagios devel lists [0] which may be accurate as a solution. Though, it requires the c code of your cgis to be patched. I took that patch in the past and ported it to Icinga including a "continue" functionality, but we've reworked that functionality ever since (countdown, etc) which might make porting backwards to Nagios not that easy. Anyways, try your luck with the old patch first.

[0] http://marc.info/?l=nagios-devel&m=127855859028072

Comment: Regarding the native nagios refresh itsself - it's done with a header refresh, not with javascript. So disabling javascript won't help here. Open cgi/status.c with your favorite editor, and grep for "refresh_rate" to see that document_header() function prints the html header (this is also what the mentioned patch manipulates by receiving the new GET param 'paused' disabling the header refresh). as said, the only way is patching the cgi c code here, unless upstream decides otherwise.